# Defining an ActiveAndroid model without creating a table

Tags: android, gson, activeandroid

I have my app's networking code separated into a separate package.  This package contains a POJO model that I'm serializing with Gson (using its `@Expose` annotation):

```
public class User {
    @Expose
    String username;

    @Expose
    String pathToAvatar;

    // etc.
}
```

My app also is using ActiveAndroid as a database wrapper.  I would like to extend the `.networking.User` model and add a couple more database-specific fields (`secretKey` or something) in my main logic.  It would be nice if the networking code did not know its model was being used in a database.  Unfortunately, I'm having to have `.networking.User` extend the ActiveAndroid `Model` base class (and having to label each networking variable with `@Column`).  This works, with one problem:  I'm getting a dummy `User` database table that corresponds with the networking code's class, even though it is not annotated with `@Table`, simply because it derives from `Model`.  The main code's table is created correctly.

Can I prevent ActiveAndroid from creating a table when it finds a certain `Model`?  Alternatively, is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: Not really.  ORMlite is seeming attractive.

Comment: Yes it is, I'm using it with https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper